# Approriate reshaping of tensor T[a1,a2,a3] to matrix M[a2,a1*a3] in python

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I am trying to reshape a tensor M[a1,a2,a3] with dimensions d1,d2,d3 to a matrix M[a2,a1*a3] of dimension d2, d1*d3. I tried with

```
M.reshape(d2,d1*d3)
```

but the result is not what it should be. To give a simple example:

```
    >>> M = np.array([[['a','b'],['c','d']],[['e','f'],['g','h']],[['i','j'],['k','l']]])
    ... array([[['a', 'b'],
     ['c', 'd']],

    [['e', 'f'],
     ['g', 'h']],

    [['i', 'j'],
     ['l', 'k']]], dtype='<U1')

    >>> M.reshape(2,3*2)
    ... array([['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
                 ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'l', 'k']], dtype='<U1')
```

Is there a way of telling reshape which axes he should 'multiply'? (Or another function that does) I'm using this in the context of matrix product states.

Thanks!

EDIT:
After the receiving some answer I might specify my question:

Given an array of dimension d1 x d2 x d3, how do I combine non-neighboring indices with reshape() and maintaining dependencies. I.e. reshaping a 3x2x2 tensor to a 2x6 matrix such that the rows correspond to the second (or third) index. As seen in the example, simple .reshape(2,6) gives neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is to first reorder the axes and then reshape:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[['a','b'],['c','d']],[['e','f'],['g','h']],[['i','j'],['k','l']]])
M = M.transpose((1, 0, 2)).reshape((M.shape[1], -1))
print(M)
```

Output:

```
[['a' 'b' 'e' 'f' 'i' 'j']
 ['c' 'd' 'g' 'h' 'k' 'l']]
```

Comment: thank you for the quick answer, this does the job it seems. Its the same as defining the tensor as M[a2,a1,a3] in the first place, which I actually tried to avoid. I am still a bit puzzled by how np.reshape() operates, it seems to me it just brute forces it into the desired shape and not caring about context of the indices. Is there a way to create/specify such context?

Comment: @Korbinian `np.reshape` just takes the data as a one-dimensional array and then rearranges it according to the given dimensions. The thing is in order to do what you want you need to actually move the data internally, which is what transposing does (actually in this case only the strides are changed, but the point is the "linearized" order changes). The "context" that you mention really is the order of the axes.

Comment: In some cases, you can use [`as_strided`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html) for cheap complex reshaping, but not here I'm afraid, because the distance between consecutive elements in the second dimension of the result is not constant.